# CSS Sprite Question

Tags: css, sprite

I've been asked to add a new link to an existing CSS Sprite.

I've attached a basic representation of the layout of the image.

[image: Here's the sprite image]

It looks from the rendered output that the markup looks something like this:

```
<div>
  <ul id="pcnatabs">
    <li id="liTab1"></li>
    <li id="liTab2">
      <a href="#" id="tab2" class="active">one</a>
    </li>
    <li id="liTab3">
      <a href="#" id="tab3">two</a>
    </li>
    <li id="liTab4">
      <a href="#" id="tab4">three</a>
    </li>
    <li id="liTab5">
      <a href="#" id="tab5">four</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

There is some existing css that is being used, however, when I modified the image to add the fifth link, I'm not having much luck in getting it to work properly. Since I haven't done a css sprite before, I'm thinking it might be best to do this in a top-down, stepwise manner and start at square 1. Can anybody suggest where I should start?

Comment: What's the current CSS? What does the "CSS Sprite" image look like, is it the image in your question?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 0):

If that is an image sprite they should share the same background-image right?

Then you only need to assign the same background image as the others, same width and height of the others, display:block, and just change the background position of the image.

Since the more links you have the more wide the image gets, probably you have to give that new link a negative background position along the x axis.

Comment: Yes, it is the image in my question.

As far as the CSS is concerned, it won't let me paste it in here...not enough room

Comment: Well, i guess they can share the same background.  I'm still not sure how this thing is working though.

I'm trying to paste the css, but it seems that there is a character limit.